# Convert Storyboard to XIB (unable to copy paste)

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I can't seem even to copy my views from storyboard into an XIB layout, as is the answer to most threads with this title. I think XCode has disabled this feature.

I've looked into manually moving the XML, but it seems that Storyboard uses a completely different (though similar) structure for views.

Is it possible, alternatively, to split up the storyboard files so that they work like XIB files?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Assistant Editor and having the files open side by side, you can then drag from one to another.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(self answered) I had created an XIB with the OS X setting instead of iOS. Additionally, after figuring this out, I disconnected the storyboard connections and used the layouts with [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"..."].